# Is it possible to create a component-local atom being asynchronously reset without an infinite loop?

Tags: ajax, clojurescript, reagent

I want to create a reagent component that has content that is changed by the handler of an ajax request. Using a local atom is yielding an infinite loop `GET`ting the resource and updating the atom, thereby triggering the re-rendering of the component.

Example:

```
(ns example
  (:require
    [reagent.core :as r]
    [ajax.core :refer [GET POST]]))

(defn get-data []
  (let [ret (r/atom "")]
    (GET "/ajax/" {:handler (partial reset! ret)})
    ret))

(defn page []
  (let [data @(get-data)]
    [:div data]))

(defn init! []
  (r/render [#'page] (.-body js/document)))
```

A "global" atom will work, as it is not recreated on each rerender:

```
(ns example
  (:require
    [reagent.core :as r]
    [ajax.core :refer [GET POST]]))

(def global-atom (r/atom ""))
(defn get-data []
  (let [ret global-atom]
    (GET "/ajax/" {:handler (partial reset! ret)})
    ret))

(defn page []
  (let [data @(get-data)]
    [:div data]))

(defn init! []
  (r/render [#'page] (.-body js/document)))
```

Is a global `def` the only possible solution, or is there a way to solve this problem with a local atom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that if you use the second form of reagent view, it should not trigger itself:

```
(defn page []
  (let [data (get-data)]
    (fn []
      [:div @data])))
```

If a view function returns a function, that function becomes the `render` function of the React component.  Otherwise the view function itself becomes `render`.